# Recurring audio issues with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: audio, ubuntu-16.04

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 on a Dell Inspiron (uname -a returns Linux  4.8.0-49-generic #52~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 10:55:59 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux). The audio device (as reported by lspci) is Intel Intel Corporation Device 9d71 (rev 21).

I'm having recurring loss of the hardware audio device at random times when I plug in a headphone into the audio jack. Subsequently, audio settings in the System Settings show no audio output or input devices. aplay -l returns PCH[HDA Intel PCH] repeated 3 times.

This is a new laptop, and there were no problems of any kind after the Xenial 16.04 was installed two weeks back. Even now, it is very robust except for the audio problem.

When this happened last week, I managed to get the audio back by installing DKMS, but the audio has failed again today and this is not working.

TIA for any pointers on why plugging in a headphone/ear-piece should result in such a catastrophic condition, and also on how to fix this permanently. Searching for audio problems on Ubuntu 16.04 results in a deluge of pages, and it is very hard to figure out which works and which would screw up my system further...

s1b

Comment: systems issues sometimes write records in the system log as viewed by running command :   dmesg

Comment: Update: None of the different ways suggested (kill pulseaudio, remove the .pulse directory and restart with -k option, purge & reinstall ALSA drivers etc) worked. Finally, what worked was `sudo apt-get upgrade`. The audio appears to be working, at least for now. I tried plugging and unplugging a headset and suspending. Audio still appears to work.

Comment: Update 2: The audio drivers have vanished again. This time too, it's after plugging in an earphone. Further, this time, `apt-get upgrade` did not work. If this doesn't get fixed, I have no option but to move out of Ubuntu.

Comment: Update 3: The problem has not gone away, but there appears to be a kind of a work-around. When I plug in an head/earphone, everything works. When I finish the session and remove the earphone, the audio devices vanish (sometimes after the next suspend/resume cycle). However, the audio devices reappear if I shut down the machine (`sudo shutdown -h 0`) for about 5 minutes and then restart.

Comment: Wonder if issue is resolved on Ubuntu 17.04  ... Might give your machine a  dual boot to see

Comment: Same here. I'm using a Dell Inspiron 14 7460. And I've tried Ubuntu 17.04, but got Dummy output after a while. Returned to 16.04 and still have no audio. After trying other approaches, I've just get rid of the audio tray icon haha it's getting worse